# how to change color of selected menu in css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<li>
    <a href="#bedroom" id="room_option_masterroom_a">
        <span id="room_option_master"></span> 
        <span id="room_option_span">Master Room</span>
    </a>
</li>

#masterroom_light_a:active{background-color:#0000FF}
```

I am trying to change color of selected menu ant it is selected until and am not select another menu from this list, i was try in CSS active tag but it is not working properly.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question with proper punctuation and grammar? And provide more HTML for context, and display the code that is not working properly?

Comment: Please try to explain properly. It's unclear what exactly is not working what do you want?

Comment: Possible (horribly written) duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531653/add-active-class-to-current-page-navigation-link

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery add class .active on menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866284/jquery-add-class-active-on-menu)

Comment: it's simple, try this : http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/btu4Lc0d/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add a class `active` to whatever menu item you click, and remove it from the other items...

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myMenu li").click(function() {
    $("#myMenu li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #0000FF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myMenu">
  <li id="item1">item1</li>
  <li id="item2">item2</li>
  <li id="item3">item3</li>
  <li id="item4">item4</li>
</ul>
```